# ZenTest 4.9.3 shows as invalid gemspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, railstutorial.org, spork, zentest

I keep getting this error when trying to run ZenTest

```
Invalid gemspec in [/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/specifications/ZenTest-4.9.3.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["< 2.1, >= 1.8"].
```

I have tried removing the ZenTest 4.9.3 and gem instal ZenTest 4.8.3 but that version cannot be found in any repositories so it automatically installs ZenTest 4.9.3 which keeps having an error and hence I cant run spork or autotest. Is there any way around this? Thanks!

Here is my gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.11'
gem 'spork'
gem 'rspec-core'
gem 'autotest', '4.4.6'
gem 'autotest-rails', '4.1.2'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'webrat'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'Zentest', '4.8.3'
end
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same problem. After digging, I found the solution. The problem is most likely to be with the version of RubyGems installed in your system. (It would be <1.8.25)

Till that version, RubyGems [didn't roundtrip gemspecs properly](https://github.com/seattlerb/zentest/issues/28#issuecomment-12592385) and thus couldn't parse "< 2.1, >= 1.8" correctly.

So, go through these steps:

```
gem uninstall ZenTest
gem update --system
gem install ZenTest
```

The problem should get solved and you should no longer receive the warnings.

Comment: Thanks Arpit! I realized I actually did those steps but I also wrote Zentest in my gemfile when it should be ZenTest which gave another error. It's resolved now. Once again, Thanks!

Comment: I am still getting these errors even after doing this. I get these erros when installing gems etc. This appears to only occur on ruby 1.9.3-p362.

Comment: Had same issue 1.9.3-p255 and ZenTest 4.9.5 and this sorted it, cheers

Comment: NOPE `Invalid gemspec in [/Users/juangallardo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/specifications/ZenTest-4.9.1.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["< 2.1, >= 1.8"]`

Comment: For me, the above didn't work, because I had ZenTest 4.9.1 in my Gemfile.lock.  Changing that to a later version [4.11]; did the trick!